# Why does python tell me that there is a syntax error in my code?

Tags: python

My code is:

```
>>> x = 25
>>> if x%2 == 0:
...     if x%10 == 0:
...         print("foo")
...     if x%7 == 0:
...         print("bar")
>>> else:
            print("baz")
```

Python keeps telling me that it has a [syntax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN27Y.png) as the picture shows. Can someone tell my why?

I asked GPT-4 on Microsoft Copilot and it told me that the code is without error.

Comment: Check the intent rules first from the official doc.

Comment: looks like indent issues

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @Friedrich Wrong, that image is useful.

Comment: Not as useful as a faithful, textual representation of whatever OP has in their editor.

Comment: @Friedrich Their textual representation is *less* useful. It lacks the context, which the image shows, and which was key to figuring out the issue. How would you change their textual representation to make it as useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Explanation

<s>Looking at your image, I can see that you have not saved your code and are instead running it in the [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop).

The `>>>` indicates a new part of code is being run in the REPL, causing the `else:` part to be run without the context of the first `if` statement.
The REPL does not see the `if` statement before and thinks you are trying to use `else` without a corresponding `if`.</s>
You have copied your code from a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) session. The REPL adds special `>>>` and `...` characters before each line of your code to show that you are inputting code and that it is not outputting the result of running code. The python [interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)) can't read those special characters and outputs an error.

## Solution

<s>You can either use [IDLE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html)'s built-in features to save your code in a python file, or copy and paste **all** of your code into the REPL at the same time.</s>
Simply remove the `>>>` and `...` characters from your code and fix the indents:

```py
x = 25
if x % 2 == 0:
    if x % 10 == 0:
        print("foo")
    elif x % 7 == 0:
        print("bar")
else:
    print("baz")
```

### Further reading

- [If ... else tutorial on W3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp)
- [Python REPL tutorial on python.land](https://python.land/introduction-to-python/the-repl)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I finally get why I constantly met the same problem over and over again!

Comment: This is just wrong. That's not the REPL, and the error is something else.

Comment: What is it, then? And what exactly is the REPL? Sorry if my answer is wrong.

Comment: That's the editor. Note the window title and menu, and the location of the problem (marked red). As far as I know you can't even reproduce this in the REPL, as you wouldn't get a new `>>>` without an empty line to indicate that you're done.

Comment: And their final line has neither `>>>` nor `...`, which isn't realistic, either. So looks like they copied some REPL session into the editor and modified it.

Comment: Oh! I see it now, thanks for pointing it out. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there might be an indentation issue in your code. Python relies on proper indentation to determine the structure of the code. In the code you provided, the indentation might not be consistent.

This is updated code:

```py
x = 25
if x % 2 == 0:
    if x % 10 == 0:
        print("foo")
    elif x % 7 == 0:
        print("bar")
else:
    print("baz")
```

Comment: What I wanted to write is a code that prints "foo" if x is even and divisible by 10, and prints "bar" is x is even and divisible by 7, and prints "baz" if x is odd.

Comment: @KWW This is what my code does check it out

Comment: Your version will print "foo" then "baz" everytime it the "foo" logic is truthy.

Comment: @OysterShucker Check now my code

Comment: @XM01-standswithPalestine Thank you! It seems that my code is problematic because the second "if" should be "elif." Can you explain why my code doesn't work? Why can't I use "if" to do the same thing that "elif" does? Big thanks to you again!

Comment: @KWW the SyntaxError you're getting isn't related to using `elif` instead of `if`. It's related to trying to enter the code into the REPL in multiple blocks. @jackssrt 's answer explains what the problem is.

Comment: @slothrop Thanks! I saw that. It solved my question. And thank you for the clarification of the problem.

Answer (score -2):

It's because you wrote the else statement in a new prompt (>>>), all you have to do is to rewrite all the script in one prompt.